# APOC import/extract JSON from CURL

Tags: node.js, json, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Problem description: I want to use `apoc.load.json`, however in a certain manner, namely instead of url or the file path use variable as argument. The reason for this is that I am sending my json as part of CURL, so I can capture it and save to variable, is there some workaround? As I need something like this (unfortunately it doesn't work, as it requires some path and not a variable):

```
var inputObject = req.body;
var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(inputObject);

.run('WITH $inputParam AS url CALL apoc.load.json(url) ...', {inputParam: jsonObject})
```

but not necessary exactly this, probably there is some other way to retrieve the json data from curl.

The curl, if it will be helpful:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d'{"origin":[{"label":"Alcohol drinks", "tag":[], "type":"string", "xpath":[]}, {"label":"Wine", "tag":["red","white"], "type":"string", "xpath":["Alcohol drinks"]}, {"label":"Port wine", "tag":["Portugal","sweet","strong"], "type":"string", "xpath":["Alcohol drinks","Wine"]}, {"label":"Sandeman Cask 33", "tag":["red","expensive"], "type":"string", "xpath":["Alcohol drinks","Wine","Port wine"]}], "target":[{"label":"Drinks", "tag":[], "type":"string", "xpath":[]}, {"label":"Tea", "tag":["black", "green"], "type":"string", "xpath":["Drinks"]}, {"label":"Carbonated water", "tag":[], "type":"string", "xpath":["Drinks","Tea"]}, {"label":"Pepsi", "tag":["sweet","cheap"], "type":"string", "xpath":["Drinks","Tea","Carbonated water"]}]}' http://localhost:3000/ontology
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you already have a variable with the desired object, why do you need an `apoc.load.json`? Just pass it as a parameter without stringify.

Comment: You are completely right, but now I've got some problems with interpreting the parameter inside the cypher query. The query is:

.run('UNWIND $inputParam AS param MERGE(label:concept{name:param.origin.label})', {inputParam: jsonObject})

Error is: Neo4jError: Type mismatch: expected a map but was String

Comment: Do not do `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Already tried, got another error:
Neo4jError: Type mismatch: expected a map but was List{Map{type -> String("string"), xpath -> List{}, label -> String("Alcohol drinks"), ...
Used "inputObject", instead of "jsonObject"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `apoc.load.json` function. Use an object without stringify transformation:

```
var inputObject = req.body;
session
  .run('UNWIND $inputParam.origin AS param MERGE(label:concept {name: param.label})', 
       {inputParam: inputObject});
```

Or pass the list as a parameter:

```
var inputObject = req.body;
session
  .run('UNWIND $inputParam AS param MERGE(label:concept {name: param.label})', 
       {inputParam: inputObject.origin});
```

P.S. You need to better understand what is objects in javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped a lot. Several notes:

Comment: Several notes:
1. I did, as you told, I haven't used apoc at all, as I already have everything, without need to load something using apoc; 
2. My mistake was exactly in cypher query, namely $imputParam I was not referring to origin ($inputParam.origin). Thus the problem was in parsing the object/parameter
Thank you again for your valuable help.